# Justifying database texts on android

Tags: android, database, android-layout, textview, android-webview

I'm working on story application pjoject for android. The story text is in the database/db file. I used textView and the text is working good on the application but it's not justified. Is there a way to justify the text from database file, or link to that tutorial?

Comment: It does no matter where the text comes from. How do you justify a TextView text? So, where is the question?

Answer (score 0):

Setting text in db won't have any styling impact on text itself. You can use third-party lib to justify your text in android.

https://github.com/bluejamesbond/TextJustify-Android

In order to use it, you'll need to use their `com.bluejamesbond.text.DocumentView` in XML instead of traditional TextView. See the first example of the following link to get an idea about code.

https://github.com/bluejamesbond/TextJustify-Android/wiki/3-%C2%B7-Examples